# How to get task and sub-task level % Complete to appear as total on summary task level % Complete

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, tasks

I created a Project Task list in SharePoint Foundation 2010. This list contains several Summary Tasks that contain Tasks. I am able to calculate the average % Complete for each task item in each Summary Task but I want that total to also appear on the Summary Task level. I was told that this function is not OOB for SharePoint 2010 nor 2013. Has anyone found a workaround to get that % Complete column to display the task % Complete total in the Summary Task level?
Thank you.